# Pronouncing position

Tags: pronunciation

I've noticed that a Russian friend is pronouncing:

- Pusition
- Cumputer
- Cumpression

I wanted to comment on it, but I first tried to confirm it, and to my surprise, I found that indeed it's supposed to be "puh·zi·shn?"

[Google search](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ925NZ925&sxsrf=APq-WBuxXnl4JJDvU3OxmwS7e6uO24osLg:1643582745824&q=how%20to%20pronounce%20position&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOMIfcRoxS3w8sc9YSnDSWtOXmPU5uINKMrPK81LzkwsyczPExLhYglJLcoV4pHi4uIoyC_OBIlasSgxpebxLGKVzMgvVyjJVygA6skHakpVgCkBAE0ReOlbAAAA&pron_lang=en&pron_country=gb&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_2OTtxtr1AhWhT2wGHaztBCAQ3eEDegQIAxAH&biw=973&bih=519&dpr=1.88)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can you confirm or deny? Since when 'O' is pronounced as 'U'?

Comment: It may sound like 'pusition' to you, but it's definitely 'position' to me.

Comment: It's as Luke Sawczak describes. When speaking slowly and carefully - dictating, for example - we might pronounce the words more "correctly". (And we might if we are the queen.) When the stress is on the **first** syllable, as in **pos**itive and **com**petent, the first vowel sound is clearly audible, while the unstressed _second_ vowel becomes a schwa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These pronunciations are correct, though individual varieties of English may have the vowel slightly more or less back and open. These are unstressed syllables, hence reduced vowels whose vowels become schwas (all the more so in the closed syllables).

Comment: "Individual varieties" means that the main stream isn't prone to that. Then, wouldn't you expect a dictionary (IPA) to pronounce a word properly without the schwa?

Comment: @ZoharLevi Indeed, I would expect dictionaries to have the schwa. I was experimenting with these yesterday and found that if I were trying to spell it out very clear syllable by syllable, I would say "PO ZI SHUN", but otherwise I would use the reduced vowel.